# Аналог webkit-fill-available для Firefox

Tags: css, css3

Мне нужно чтобы блок Child Div был по высоте как Parent DIV, но не превышал его.
Для этого я прописал:

```
.parent {
height: 100%;
}
.child {
height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

В хроме и опере это работает замечательно, но Firefox не поддерживает, не понимаю как сделать тоже самое там, помогите.

Comment: Ваш html код приведите, пожалуйста

Comment: @Coder Я затрудняюсь какой кусок кода там нужно скинуть, речь о меню, неизвестно может что-то вне кода меню мешает отображению. [Ссылка](https://xn--74-7lchafv.xn--p1ai/) на сайт. Выпадающее окошко при наведении на пункты меню на высоту родителя (только в хроме получилось сделать), в Firefox не работает приведенное вами решение (сам его изначально пробовал), и я не могу понять в чем причина.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.parent {
height: 100%;
}
.child {
    height: 100%;
    height: -moz-available;          /* WebKit игнор. */
    height: -webkit-fill-available;  /* Mozilla игнор. */
    height: fill-available;
}
```

Comment: "height: fill-available;" Mozilla пишет что нет такого свойства

Comment: Да без разницы - работает, или нет? - а то уберите, ежели есть желание

Comment: Не работает, поэтому и пишу.

Comment: Ну что ж - тогда нужно ждать - может, кто еще что подскажет. Хотя - попробуйте добавить !important к каждой инструкции.

Answer (score 0):

### У меня была похожая проблема с изображением

Я подставлял свойство `height: -webkit-fill-available;` всё было хорошо.
Но я отказался от него.

У меня было сделано всё на grid сетке.

У родителя прописал `grid-auto-rows: minmax(auto, 100%);`

Изображение у меня было вставлено через тег `<img>`

Поэтому я задал свойство `object-fit: cover;`

Для изображения я задал `width: 100%;` `height: 100%;` и что-бы оно не вылазило я применил `overflow: hidden;`